# How to post a custom event of a wxWebview object to its parent in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to send a drop event to the parent of wxWebview object. I know that wxWebView consumes all received events and I have to create a custom event for its parent. I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
void onNewWindow( wxWebViewEvent& evt )
    {
      wxString* files = new wxString[ 1 ];
      files[ 0 ] = evt.GetURL();
      wxDropFilesEvent dropEvent( wxEVT_DROP_FILES, 1, files );
      dropEvent.SetEventObject( ctrl_->GetParent() );
      dropEvent.m_pos.x = 0;
      dropEvent.m_pos.y = 0;
      ctrl_->GetParent()->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent( dropEvent );
      // we don't want to open a new window so veto the event
      evt.Veto();
    }
```

When I drop a file into the wxWebview, it does not work but if I drop it on its parent, program works as expected. I am not sure what's going on and whether I have set the correct drop event for the parent or not.

I also tried to set a hook for the message received in the child of wxWebView in Windows by overriding the `MSWWindowProc` function and `SetWindowsHookEx` but so far I have not succeeded.

I am using wxWidgets 3.2.2.1 with edge backend in Windows 10 and other platform are not important at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what do you mean by "work". If this just means "execute the handler bound to `wxEVT_DROP_FILES` in the parent", then this should work, but I'm not sure how is it really useful considering that you could just bind the same handler to the same event on `ctrl_` directly.

If you mean "do exactly the same thing as if the file were dropped on the parent", then you can't do this at wx level because part of this "thing" is what is done by Windows itself when it gets `WM_DROPFILES` in `DefWindowProc()` and, of course, you can't trigger execution of this code by sending wx events as Windows doesn't know anything about them. So to do this you would indeed need to forward the Windows message instead.

But it's still not clear at all why exactly do you think you need to do all this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide me an example or any references that shows how to forward the Windows message to the parent? I tried setting a hook but it does not catch the message. It seems that Chrome starts a new process for every process and consume the event there. I am stuck